# Page header menu links change

Tags: menus, permalinks, pages, headers, custom-header

I am trying to find out where the header menu links on my WP is located so that i can change the URL of the page.

the link is: http://blahblah.com/?page_id=11

and i need to change it to: http://blahblah.com/?page_id=36

However, i do not see anywhere in the menus that i have to change that link. I even looked into the mySQL database **wp_posts** and tried changing all references to 11 to 36 but it still comes up 11!??!

Where could i be overlooking it?

The appearance Menus page:

[image: header menu]

And the header page itself:

[image: header page]

And the header code:

[image: navcode]

Comment: Leaving page IDs aside for the moment: **why** are you trying to make this change? What are you ultimately trying to *accomplish*?

Comment: To send the "doctors" page to a different page id.

Comment: Again: ignore Page IDs. Why do you want to send the "Doctors" page elsewhere?

Comment: For example, this is what I'm *thinking* you're trying to do: "*I want to display a different page in the header menu, with the same "Our Doctors" menu title*"

Comment: @ChipBennett Yes that would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you're using a *Custom* Nav Menu, meaning that the contents of the menu can be *customized*.

The easiest solution is simply to:

- *remove* the current "Our Doctors" page from the menu
- *add* your desired page to the menu
- *edit* the menu item to change the displayed title to "Our Doctors"
- save the menu